# Trigger to count elements

Tags: oracle, triggers

There is a MODEL table as follow

```
create table MODEL (
model_name VARCHAR(20),
model_year NUMBER,
consumption VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
Component component_ty_nt,
Distributor distributor_ty_nt,
Car car_ty_nt,
constraint t_pk primary key (Model_Name, Model_Year))
nested table Component store as component_ty_nt_TAB
nested table Distributor store as distributor_ty_nt_TAB
nested table Car store as car_ty_nt_TAB
```

the Component_ty

```
Create or replace type Component_ty as object (
Code VARCHAR(10),
Component_Description VARCHAR(100),
Component_Type VARCHAR(10))
NOT FINAL;
```

has component_type attribute which can be 'body', 'engine' or 'equipment'

Every time I perform an INSERT on this table I need a trigger that checks that there are at least 3 components inserted, for which 1 must be of type 'engine' and one must be of type 'body'.
Any suggestion?

For what concern the number of elements this trigger returns the following errors

```
create or replace trigger number_of_components 
after insert on Model
for each row
declare
componentNumber NUMBER;
BEGIN 
select 
c.component_number INTO componentNumber from model m
outer apply (select count(*) as component_number from table(component)) c
where m.model_name = :new.model_name AND m.model_year = :new.model_year;
if componentNumber < 3 then
    raise_application_error(-20061, 'Not enough components');
end if;
end;

ora-04091: table DB_EXAM.Model it mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ora-06512: at "DB_EXAM.NUMBER_OF_COMPONENT", line 4
ora-04088: error during execution of trigger'DB_EXAM.NUMBER_OF_COMPONENT'
```

what am I doing wrong? and how can I check for the constraint on the type within the same trigger? Or is it better a new trigger?

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to select from the table. Use the `:NEW` record containing each inserted row and the `COUNT` attribute of the collection (also the error code needs to be between -20000 and -20999 for a user-defined exception). Then to check the types of component then just loop through each component and check the type:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER number_of_components 
AFTER INSERT ON Model
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  has_engine PLS_INTEGER := 0;
  has_body   PLS_INTEGER := 0;
BEGIN 
  IF :NEW.component.COUNT < 3 THEN
    raise_application_error(-20061, 'Not enough components');
  END IF;

  FOR i IN 1 .. :NEW.component.COUNT LOOP
    IF :NEW.component(i).component_type = 'engine' THEN
      has_engine := 1;
    ELSIF :NEW.component(i).component_type = 'body' THEN
      has_body := 1;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  IF has_engine = 0 OR has_body = 0 THEN
    raise_application_error(-20061, 'Does not have engine and body.');
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Then for the types/table:

```sql
Create or replace type Component_ty as object (
  Code                  VARCHAR(10),
  Component_Description VARCHAR(100),
  Component_Type        VARCHAR(10)
)
NOT FINAL;

CREATE TYPE component_ty_nt IS TABLE OF component_ty;

create table MODEL (
  model_name VARCHAR(20),
  model_year NUMBER,
  consumption VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
  Component component_ty_nt,
  --Distributor distributor_ty_nt,
  --Car car_ty_nt,
  constraint t_pk primary key (Model_Name, Model_Year)
)
nested table Component store as component_ty_nt_TAB
--nested table Distributor store as distributor_ty_nt_TAB
--nested table Car store as car_ty_nt_TAB
;
```

If you use:

```
INSERT INTO model (model_name, model_year, consumption, component)
VALUES ('A', 1900, 'X', component_ty_nt());
```

Then the error is:

> ```
> ORA-20061: Not enough components
> ORA-06512: at "FIDDLE_CVZJKWFQKTBCNENJZAKH.NUMBER_OF_COMPONENTS", line 3
> ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'FIDDLE_CVZJKWFQKTBCNENJZAKH.NUMBER_OF_COMPONENTS'
> ```

But if you use:

```
INSERT INTO model (model_name, model_year, consumption, component)
VALUES ('A', 1900, 'X', component_ty_nt(
  component_ty('A', 'A', 'body'),
  component_ty('B', 'B', 'engine'),
  component_ty('C', 'C', 'equipment')
));
```

Then it works.

---

To answer you second question, don't use the trigger, add a constraint to the nested table:

```sql
ALTER TABLE component_ty_nt_tab 
  ADD CONSTRAINT component_type__chk
  CHECK (component_type IN ('body', 'engine', 'equipment'));
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8xKYvi-v)

Comment: the constraint should be about the fact that there must be exactly one component of type 'body' and one component of type 'engine' for each model inserted.

Comment: @mikerug88 Your code only checks the number of components. To check the types then just loop through the collection and check the types.